# Issues with RedirectResult used within AuthorizeAttribute attribute in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-action-filter

I have to deal with a legacy application where the redirect to a resource that requires authentication does not work. Meaning that the usual:

```
Login?returnUrl=targetThatNeedsAuthentication
```

is not even generated.

The situation is as follows. There is an implementation of:

```
AuthorizeAttribute
```

which, as usual contains:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    ...
    var url = // get url of resource that requires authentication
    filterContext.Result = new NewResult(url, false);
}
```

Here url is something like:

```
/membersonly/Login?redirectUrl=http://localhos:1234/targetThatNeedsAuthentication/
```

Which is generated correctly. The implementation uses the NewResult, which inherits from `RedirectResult`, has a constructor like this:

```
public NewResult(string url, bool preserveForm) : base(url)
```

Any ideas why the base constructor may not work as expected?

Comment: what exactly is not working? redirection?

Comment: yeah the base controller of RedirectResult, which receives url, does not redirect or set it correctly ...

Comment: You need to inherit or return a "[HttpUnauthorizedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)" instead of your new class or what you can do is set the correct status code on you result to 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Can you post code of your NewResult. I'm wonder how you changed RedirectResult.

Comment: Can you be more clear? What happens now and what you want to achieve? is problem name of query parameter or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I used in one of the projects:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary 
    {
        { "action", "LogIn" },
        { "controller", "Account" },
        { "returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl}
    });
}
```

Then in the AccountController I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult LogIn(LogInModel modelData, string returnUrl = "")
{
  // check authorization
  ...

  if (user != null) // user is authorized
  {
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
      return Redirect(returnUrl);
    else
      // return to default authorized page
  }
}
```

Obviously, you'd need to adapt it for your case.